# Git clone without username and password

Tags: git

I'd like to use `git clone https://...` without using `username` and `password`, it doesn't work on my server.

Command : `sudo git clone https://gitlab.com/****/****.git`

Issue : They ask me the username and password.

Using SSH, they ask me the passphrase, and I don't want to input something after `git clone`.

Any ideas?

**Edit #1**

Command : `sudo ssh-keygen -p -P "myoldpassword" -n "" -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Result :

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Bad passphrase.
```

Comment: If it's a private or otherwise access-restricted repository, not much else you can do besides configure SSH access.  Do you have that enabled?

Comment: Yes, it's a private repository. And yes I have SSH enabled, but with a passphrase and I don't want them...

Answer (score 1):

> Using SSH, they ask me the passphrase, and I don't want to input something after git clone

To remove the passphrase from your ssh key you need to run

```
$ ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```

There is also the option of using ssh-agent, which can cache the passphrase for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. This will make your key read-only, and will allow you to use it.